# chrome cannot display special characters é though it shows correctly in text editor

Tags: html, google-chrome

i have a html file which has special character 'Démonstration'. when i can checked the file in text editor, it shows correctly, but when i open the html file in chrome, it becomes 'Demonstration'. I've set the charset to 'UTF-8' as shown below:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

why it still wont' work?

Alsow tried in Firefox and Safari, it won't show up correctly. is it something wrong with the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the é with `&#233;`

You can view the html codes for special characters here http://www.starr.net/is/type/htmlcodes.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're using windows, you can hit the run command and type "charmap".   And then copy the special character you want.  The character é is under the Haettenschweiler font.  Then paste it in your markup.  Tested in Chrome.